# Allow Non-OPs to claim their own regions

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bukkit

I just installed Bukkit server. I have three plugins: Essentials, WorldEdit, WorldGuard. I have configured permissons so that users have all WorldEdit and WorldGuard commands available:

```
- 'worldedit.*'
- 'worldguard.*'
```

I noticed it doesn't work if users aren't OPs(`You don't have permissons to do this`), but ops can use these both plugins. But I saw on other servers that non-op claimed their regions. How to allow users to use these commands if they aren't OPs?

Comment: Could you provide slightly more information? What Permissions plugin are you using?

Comment: @Jake King Essentials

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you still have this issue, but bukkit has removed wildcard support on permissions.

Bukkit has an in house permissions engine, but needs a plugin to tell it which users have which permissions. The in house permissions engine does not support wildcards and it doesn't matter which permissions plugin you have installed.

Learn to use parent/child permissions and groups.

Read http://forums.bukkit.org/threads/permissions-faq.25080/ for more details, it is under the "for everyone" spoiler.